# Kids cars inside the toilet

Tags: toilet

My kid threw small cars into the toilet and opened the water, we tried to open the clogging with pompa and it didn't help ... how can you fix or call a professional?

Comment: How do you feel about ... ... reaching ...  "in there"?

Comment: What is "pompa"? Do you mean a plunger?  Reach on in there. You're on a DIY site, so do it yourself. If that doesn't help, detach the toilet and turn it over. That's also a we'll documented DIY job.

Comment: might be able to use a magnet on a string for die-cast cars.

Comment: Quit with the plunger, that's only making it worse. But it might work if you depress it slowly and then pull back real fast. *Then* you reach in there. You *will* get sprayed or you're not doing it right.

Comment: Gives new meaning to "My car is a crapper."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A wet dry shop vac pushed into the toilet trap while turned on may grab the cars I have actually done this several times some times they get stuck in the vacuum hose sometimes hanging on at the opening. Try putting the hose in several times until no cars come out, if you come up empty they may be in the pipe below.